# ezPublish: eZTemplate:elementValue: Missing array data structure, got NULL

Tags: php, ezpublish

We have received below error in the error log file:

> eZTemplate:elementValue: Missing array data structure, got NULL

In the respective file have below script:

```
{* Load JavaScript dependencys + JavaScriptList *}

page_footer_script.tpl {if and(get_browser().majorver|le(8),get_browser().name|eq('msie'))} {ezscript_load( array(ezini( 'JavaScriptSettingsie8', 'FrontendFooterJavaScriptList', 'design.ini' ) ) )} {else} {ezscript_load( array(ezini( 'JavaScriptSettings', 'FrontendFooterJavaScriptList', 'design.ini' ) ) )} {/if}
```

Thanks 
Sunil

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is there same error for both conditions?

I dont see anything wrong in that code... I think problem is somewere else... Hard to tell.

Also try to add on the end:

> |prepend( 'ezjsc::jquery', 'ezjsc::jqueryio' )

Example:

```
 {ezscript_load( ezini( 'JavaScriptSettings', 'BackendJavaScriptList', 'design.ini' )|prepend( 'ezjsc::jquery', 'ezjsc::jqueryio' ) )}
```

Maybe this documentation will be a hint for u:

http://share.ez.no/learn/ez-publish/ezjscore-ez-publish-javascript-and-ajax-framework/(page)/4